# Python trying to send email with smtplib not working

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to send emails with python and smtplib but whenever I try to it gives me an error

my code:

```py
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

subject = "email from python"
body = "this is a test"
sender_email = "email"
receiver_email = "email"
password = input("enter password")


message = EmailMessage()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message["Subject"] = subject
message.set_content(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context()

print("working")
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context = context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string)
print("sent")
```

but when I try that it gives me this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context = context) as server:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1057, in _get_socket
    new_socket = self.context.wrap_socket(new_socket,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

I have no idea what is causing this
Thanks!

Comment: Failure to verify the certificate might be caused by the local trust store not being properly setup (make sure to use [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/)) or that the certificate is not the expected one. The latter might happen when something is actively inferring with the connection, like some antivirus, corporate proxies or captive portals do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it shows problem in `ssl.c` which means C/C++ library [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) and sometimes it needs to install newer version of `OpenSSL`. It is not Python module and you can't install it with `pip`. But first try `certifi` as in first comment.